# Discrepancy in performance between log division and log subtraction using numba

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I am trying to optimize some code that uses logs (the mathematical kind, not the timestamp record kind :)) and I found something strange that I haven't been able to find any answers for online. We have log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b), so I have written some code to compare the performance of the two methods.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

# create some large random walk data
x = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, int(1e7))
x = abs(x.min()) + 100 + x  # make all values >= 100

@nb.njit
def subtract_log(arr, tau):
    """arr is a numpy array, tau is an int"""
    for t in range(tau, arr.shape[0]):
        a = np.log(arr[t]) - np.log(arr[t - tau])
    return None

@nb.njit
def divide_log(arr, tau):
    """arr is a numpy array, tau is an int"""
    for t in range(tau, arr.shape[0]):
        a = np.log(arr[t] / arr[t - tau])
    return None

%timeit subtract_log(x, 100)
>>> 252 ns ± 0.319 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit divide_log(x, 100)
>>> 5.57 ms ± 48.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So we see that subtracting logs is ~20,000 times faster than dividing by logs. I find this strange because I would have thought that in subtracting logs, the log series approximation would have to be calculated **twice**. But perhaps it's something to do with how numpy broadcasts operations?

The above example is trivial as we don't do anything with the result of the calculation. Below is a more realistic example where we return the result of the calculation.

```
@nb.njit
def subtract_log(arr, tau):
    """arr is a numpy array, tau is an int"""
    out = np.empty(arr.shape[0] - tau)
    for t in range(tau, arr.shape[0]):
        f = t - tau
        out[f] = np.log(arr[t]) - np.log(arr[f])
    return out

@nb.njit
def divide_log(arr, tau):
    """arr is a numpy array, tau is an int"""
    out = np.empty(arr.shape[0] - tau)
    for t in range(tau, arr.shape[0]):
        f = t - tau
        out[f] = np.log(arr[t] / arr[f])
    return out

out1 = subtract_log(x, 100)
out2 = divide_log(x, 100)
np.testing.assert_allclose(out1, out2, atol=1e-8)  # True

%timeit subtract_log(x, 100)
>>> 129 ms ± 783 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit divide_log(x, 100)
>>> 93.4 ms ± 257 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Now we see the times are the same order of magnitude, but subtracting logs is some 40% slower than dividing.

Can anyone explain these discrepancies?

1. Why is subtracting logs so much faster than dividing logs for the trivial case?
2. Why is subtracting logs 40% slower than dividing logs when we store the value in an array? I know there is significant setup cost in initializing an array `np.empty()` - initializing an array in `subtract_log()` in the trivial case, but **without** storing values in it brings the time up from 252ns to 311us.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't measure "useless" things, a compiler may optimize it completely away**

If you turn of division by zero check (error_model="numpy"), both functions take about 280ns. Not because of fast calculation, but because they are actually doing nothing.
Optimizing away useless calculations is expected, but sometimes LLVM can't detect all of it.

In the second case you are comparing the runtime of 2 logarithms, to 1 logarithm and one division. (the substractions/additions as well as multiplications are a lot faster). There can be differences in calculation time, depending on the log implementation and the processor. But also have a look at the results, they are not exactly the same.

At least for a floa64 division (FDIV) you can have a look at the [instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals)
from Agner Fog.